# How can I integrate a system to track a tractor's movements in a field using GPS?

Tags: electrical-engineering, transportation

I work in agriculture and I'd like to track my tractors "trips".

What I'm looking for is a device that will record this data using GPS, and send it to a database to later process it.

I mention GPS because the signal is pretty decent in all of the fields my tractor works in, but would there be alternatives?

There is also decent phone service and a wifi spot nearby.

Comment: Modern agricultural machinery has this built-in, plus the ability to combine the position data with custom-generated maps to control the machinery (e.g. if the soil quality varies within a field, the rate of spreading fertilizer etc can be automatically controlled as the tractor drives over the field). This seems like a "shopping" question not an "engineering" question IMO. See https://www.gps.gov/applications/agriculture/ fpr example.

Comment: I'm aware but I live in a third world country and don't really have access to that lol. I want to install this myself.

Comment: Sure, but I don't suppose you are doing to design and build your own GPS receiver and the computing hardware to interface with it, and then write all the software yourself! If you just want to log where your tractor is being driven, you could just get one of the cellphone apps used by runners or cyclists for doing the same thing. Many of them are free (assuming you already have a phone).

Comment: Definitely not lol. I'm looking for a gps receiver that already sends the data to a server if given internet access, for me to later request that data and analyze it, map it, etc.

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! This looks like a [resource-hunting question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/10/1832). Such questions are prone to becoming out-dated, and are therefore considered off-topic for this site.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but these are great educational devices. Adafruit.com sells GPS receiver boards, ~30-USD. These can talk to small SBC (single board computers) such as Gemma M0, 10-USD, Trinket M0, 9-USD, and many others, even arduino.cc devices. Lots to choose from and highly versatile. Even Raspberry Pi. Search the first listed site for GPS, then Gemma M0, and then Trinket M0. There are also Feather SBC from R-Pi on the same website.

Data loggers can store the data, and you can write programs to read and print out the data

You'll have to learn programming and to read IO, but you'll really learn some great stuff.